# Replacing Null attribute with the value of the nearest feature

Tags: merge, fme-form, null

I have several polygons with "Null" values that I would like to give them the "Name' of their nearest polygonal feature. As you see in the photo, the light green polygon is actually a part of the purple polygon, but it is separated because it has null name and not the same name as the parent polygon. Any idea how can I assign the same name to both polygon in order to end up with one harmonised feature using FME, Please?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The transformer you want is the [**NeighborFinder**](https://docs.safe.com/fme/2020.2/html/FME_Desktop_Documentation/FME_Transformers/Transformers/neighborfinder.htm). The NeighborFinder has Base and Candidate ports. You want to put your "NULL" features linked to the base port and the other ones to the Candidate port.

[image]

There is an option for Attribute Accumulation. I recommend setting it to "Prefix Candidate" that way, all of your merged features will have attributes of both.

[image]

Then you can do some post-processing in an [**AttributeManager**](https://docs.safe.com/fme/2020.2/html/FME_Desktop_Documentation/FME_Transformers/Transformers/attributemanager.htm) to set the NULL values to the resulting closest feature.